# App installation/download in Google and Apple Store through R or Python

Tags: python, r, installation, powerbi

I have a dashboard about one App with some metrics. The dashboard is refresh everyday and run totally automatic, except App installation. 
Everyday I need to go to google and apple store to download this information manually.

There are any way to download through R or Python my App installations?

Regards
Kardu